# Standalone ELSE in BI Publisher RTF Templates

Tags: oracle, rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

I understand that there is an [IF-ELSE Statement in XML Publisher RTF Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-04477E49-F671-4BF1-8353-06A7CDEAD2CC.htm#BIPRD2480), that goes something like below:

`<?xdofx:if ELEMENT1='A' then 'The Letter is A' else 'The Letter is not A' end if?>`

However, i'm looking to use the `IF` statement in showing different data tables depending on the value. Something like the below pseudo code:

`IF BUSINESS_GROUP IS BG-A THEN SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS A B and C, IF NOT, then SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS X Y and Z`

I was able to do this by using 2 separate IF Statements:

`<?xdofx:if BUSINESS_GROUP='A'> SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS A B and C <?end if?>`

`<?xdofx:if BUSINESS_GROUP!='A'> SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS X Y and Z <?end if?>`

I'm hoping that I can just use a statement like `<?ELSE?>`but it does not work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter Paff showed, `<?choose:?>` is a good route to go.  It can be a little "bulky", but if you ever need to add more conditions it seems to become easier to follow.

There is another (perhaps "bulkier") option for your very specific condition: If the `TABLE` you reference is one table and you are only wanting to show/hide certain columns of that table based on conditions, you could add those conditions to each column (or group of columns) that you wish to show (or hide) using: `<?if@column:?>`.

For details see [Oracle Fusion Middleware Report Designer's Guide for Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher 12.2.1.2.0 -> Creating RTF Templates -> Using Conditional Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-04477E49-F671-4BF1-8353-06A7CDEAD2CC.htm#BIPRD2480) - especially the section on Formatting Columns.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is no standalone 'else' block. For your requirements, you will need to use to if expressions evaluating opposite conditions.

[Here](https://cleartext.blogspot.com/2009/07/bip-if-then-else.html) is a list of all the different ways an if expression can be used in BIP.

Answer (score 0):

The following satisfies your functional requirement, but it's not an `if else` statement.

```
<?choose:?>
   <?when: BUSINESS_GROUP='A'?>
      SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS A B and C
   <?end when?>
   <?otherwise:?>
      SHOW TABLE with COLUMNS X Y and Z
   <?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```

This is comparable to a switch/case/evaluate statement in other programming languages.

Comment: just to add, i believe WHEN does not allow multiple conditions (i.e. when BUSINESS_GROUP = 'A' and SOURCE='X')?